# Rounding with a .0 included

Tags: php

I'm looking to round so that the zero is included, for example:

We round 2.99 to 3, so it displays 3. I want it to instead display 3.0.

I'm going to move this value to the database afterwards, if that matters.

I've found a solution with sprintf, which didn't work due to the reason mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: you could just do an `echo ".0";` after outputting the rounded number.

Comment: @chands This is not a great solution

Comment: @chands that would require an if statement, which is a lot of inconvenience and far from perfect code.

Comment: Seeing the answers, I guess I didn't quite understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `number_format(round(2.99, 1), 1)`. First it rounds to the proper position, then add a zero (and turns it into a string).

But you do NOT need the .0 in your database - it will ignore that. Not only that but it will be a string, so it might not work right with bound variables.

If you want the .0 to show in the database output you may be able to configure that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function and set 1 as second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `number_format` function found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)